# problem with mysql

Tags: mysql

mysql or mysql_secure_installation

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'pc123'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

mysqld

```
[Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 15173
[Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
[Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
[ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
[System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I just installed mysql, what's the problem?

Comment: Usually mysql strats ony with user root with all privileges and you have to add all user do you need and grant this users permissions

Comment: Which version?  What OS?  Changing `lower_case_table_names` is dangerous.  Be root when you install.

Answer (score 0):

You had tried

```
mysql (without any parameter)
```

which is the first mistake - the error (using password: NO) will be thrown for that.

For the first time

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and give root password to enter in. And then

```
create database db1;
create user user1@localhost identified by 'user1pwd';
grant all on db1.* to user1@localhost;
```

And next time you shall login through

```
mysql -u user1 -p
```

and have access to **only db1**.

(please note: if pc123 is your system user and you prefer this username to be used for mysql too, replace user1 with pc123).